# "Deep Copy" sem a importação do módulo "copy"?

Tags: python

Existe alguma outra maneira de realizar uma "Deep Copy" de objetos em Python sem utilizar método [`deepcopy()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy) da biblioteca padrão [`copy`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html) ?

O código abaixo poderia ser escrito de outra maneira ?

```
import copy

class Xpto:
    pass

lst = [ Xpto(), Xpto() ]
copy = copy.deepcopy(lst)

print( "Original: %s = %s" % (id(lst),[ id(i) for i in lst ]))
print( "Copia   : %s = %s" % (id(copy),[ id(i) for i in copy ]))
```

Possível saída:

```
Original: 140635532213960 = [140635657043304, 140635657043248]
Copia   : 140635532235400 = [140635657043528, 140635657043472]
```

Comment: Chegou a analisar o [código fonte](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/copy.py) desta biblioteca para ser como é feito?

Comment: E por quê você quer fazer isso sem importar o método `copy`? muitos desses módulos da biblioteca padrão do Python já são usados internamente pelo próprio Python - você não tem nenhuma penalidade ao importar o módulo `copy`.

Comment: @jsbueno: Você está certo! O módulo `copy` faz parte da biblioteca padrão do Python. Porém, o intento da pergunta é puramente "didático", e talvez, uma boa resposta possa **ampliar os horizontes** de toda comunidade a respeito do assunto e dos mecanismos internos da linguagem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O módulo copy e suas principais funçoes `copy.copy` e `copy.deepcopy` são bastante úteis, e devem ser usados sem restrições sempre que se precisar de suas funcionalidades.

Uma coisa interessante, tanto do copy quanto deepcopy é que eles fazem mais do que copiar estruturas de dicionários, listas, números e strings - ou seja, o tipo de dados que costuamos serializar como JSON em aplicações modernas: eles realmente fazem cópias de objetos Python arbitrários, inclusive instâncias de classes criadas pelo usuário.

E isso envolve uma série de "corner cases" - a grosso modo, o "copy" de um objeto arbitrário de Python pode ser feito chamando explicitamente o método `__new__` da class de um objeto, e então atribuindo-se ao `__dict__` da nova instância criada uma cópia do `__dict__` do primeiro objeto:

```
class MinhaClasse: 
   ...

m = MinhaClasse()
m.atributo = 10

m1 = m.__class__.__new__()
m1.__dict__ = m.__dict__.copy()
```

Pronto, m1 é uma cópia de m, com "profundidade 2"

Dito isso, em geral quando pensamos no deepcopy o que temos em mãos é justamente uma estrutura de dados como a que mencionei acima: um conjunto arbitrário de primitivas dentro de dicionários e listas.  Uma versão do deepcopy que funcione só pra isso pode ser feita de forma recursiva - sempre que encontrar uma lista ou dicionário, ela chama ela mesma, senão, faz a atribuição ao novo objeto:

```
def mycopy(data):
    if isinstance(data, dict):
        result = {}
        for key, value in data.items():
            result[key] = mycopy(value)
    elif isinstance(data, list):
        result = []
        for item in data:
            result.append(mycopy(item))
    elif isinstance(data, (int, float, type(None), str, bool)):
        result = data
    else:
        raise ValueError("Unrecognized type for mycopy function")
    return result
```

Esta função "mycopy" é tudo o que é necessário para criar deepcopies de estrutura JSON. Ela pode ser melhorada para estrutura de daods arbitrárias de Python que contenham tuples e sets - mas para fazer funcionar com containers arbitrários, por exemplo, classes personalizadas, ainda faltaria muita coisa.

Em suma, como o codigo para um "deepcopy" simples pode ser algo instrutivo de se entender, incluí o meu aí, mas como está nos comentários, a recomendação é realmente usar o copy e o deepcopy

Comment: Obrigado, sua resposta foi de grande valia!

Answer (score 2):

A partir da resposta do usuário @jsbueno, fui capaz de entender melhor a complexidade do assunto com o qual estou lidando.

Depois de muitos testes e diferentes abordagens, por fim, cheguei ao seguinte código:

```
def my_deepcopy(data):
    if isinstance(data, dict):
        result = {}
        for key, value in data.items():
            result[key] = my_deepcopy(value)

        assert id(result) != id(data)

    elif isinstance(data, list):
        result = []
        for item in data:
            result.append(my_deepcopy(item))

        assert id(result) != id(data)

    elif isinstance(data, tuple):
        aux = []
        for item in data:
            aux.append(my_deepcopy(item))
        result = tuple(aux)

        assert id(result) != id(data)

    elif isinstance(data, (int, float, complex, type(None), str, bool )):
        result = data

    elif isinstance(data, set ):
        result = set(data)

        assert id(result) != id(data)

    elif isinstance(data, bytearray ):
        result = bytearray(data)

        assert id(result) != id(data)

    elif hasattr( data, '__name__' ):
        result = data

    elif hasattr( data, '__class__'):
        aux = {}
        result = data.__class__()

        for k, v in data.__dict__:
            aux[k] = my_deepcopy(v)
            assert id(aux[k]) != id(v)

        result.__dict__ = aux

        assert id(result) != id(data)

    else:
        raise ValueError("unexpected type")

    return result

# Funcao
def FooBar():
    return "FooBar"

# Classe
class Xpto:
    pass

# Tipos para teste
lst_obj = [ 0, 1.1, 'foo', 'bar' ]
dict_obj = { 'zero' : 0, 'pi' : 3.1415, 'desc' : 'foobar' }
list_list_obj = [ [1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9] ]
tuple_list_obj = [ (-1,-1), (0,-1,0), (-1,0), (0,0,0,0) ]
dict_list_obj = [ {'zero' : 0}, {'pi' : 3.1415}, {'desc' : 'foobar'} ]
list_set_obj = [ set([1,2,3]), set([1,2,3])]
list_bytearray_obj = [ bytearray([1,2,3]), bytearray([1,2,3])  ]
list_func_obj = [ FooBar, FooBar ]
list_arbitrary_obj = [ Xpto(), Xpto() ]

# Testando
my_deepcopy( lst_obj )
my_deepcopy( dict_obj )
my_deepcopy( list_list_obj )
my_deepcopy( tuple_list_obj )
my_deepcopy( dict_list_obj )
my_deepcopy( list_set_obj )
my_deepcopy( list_bytearray_obj )
my_deepcopy( list_func_obj )
my_deepcopy( list_arbitrary_obj )
```